# Will last of a lazy seq evaluate all elements in clojure?

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

Let's assume that we have an expensive computation `expensive`. If we consider that `map` produces a lazy seq, then does the following evaluate the function `expensive` for all elements of the mapped collection or only for the last one?

```
(last
  (map expensive '(1 2 3 4 5)))
```

I.e. does this evaluate `expensive` for all the values 1..5 or does it only evaluate `(expensive 5)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole collection will be evaluated. A simple test answers your question.

```
=> (defn exp [x]
     (println "ran")
     x)
=> (last
     (map exp '(1 2 3 4 5)))
ran
ran
ran
ran
ran
5
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no random access for lazy sequences in Clojure.

In a way, you can consider them equivalent to singly linked lists - you always have the current element and a function to get the next one.

So, even if you just call `(last some-seq)` it will evaluate all the sequence elements even if the sequence is lazy.If the sequence is finite and reasonably small (and if you don't hold the head of the sequence in a reference) it's fine when it comes to memory. As you noted, there is a problem with execution time that may occur if the function used to get the next element is expensive.

In that case, you can make a compromise so that you use a cheap function to walk all the way to  the last element:

`(last some-seq)`

and then apply the function only on that result:

`(expensive (last some-seq))`

Comment: Or you can use delay/force: `(let [s (map #(delay (expensive %)) some-seq)] (force (last s)))`. This is more flexible, since it lets you realize whatever elements you want without having to worry about computing the expensive function multiple times.

Comment: @amalloy: Nice, thanks! I always prefer the simplest solution and I think that (within given context) my solution is one. Still, having a macro that can explicitly 'lazify' a function even more is awesome. Btw, your comment is answer-worthy.

Answer (score 1):

last will always force the evaluation of the lazy sequence - this is clearly necessary as it needs to find the end of the sequence, and hence needs to evaluate the lazy seq at every position.

If you want laziness in all the idividual elements, one way is to create a sequence of lazy sequences as follows:

```
(defn expensive [n]
  (do 
    (println "Called expensive function on " n)
    (* n n)))

(def lzy (map #(lazy-seq [(expensive %)]) '(1 2 3 4 5)))

(last lzy)
=> Called expensive function on  5
=> (25)
```

Note that last in this case still forces the evaluation of the top-level lazy sequence, but doesn't force the evaluation of the lazy sequences contained within it, apart from the last one that we pull out (because it gets printed by the REPL).